# Проблема в if else

Tags: javascript

Если в prompt нажать на отмену(null), то выходит сообщение **Для проверки введите слово "Да" или "Da"**, по задумке это сообщение не должно выходить, если пользователь нажмёт на отмену. Если нажата кнопка отмена должно выходить только одно сообщение **'Вы отменили проверку'**. Как исправить этот косяк?

```js
let check = prompt('Проверить');
let LowerCase = ''; 

if(check == null){                          // Почему после своего alert выводит alert из else?
alert(`Вы отменили проверку`);              
}

if(check != null){
LowerCase = check.toLowerCase();              // Нечувствительноть к регистру 
} 
 
if(LowerCase == 'da' || LowerCase == 'да'){
alert(`Проверка прошла успешно`);   
}
    
else{
alert(`Для проверки введите слово "Да" или "Da"`); // Почему выходит это сообщение, если нажата null?
}
```

Comment: Ваш `else` относится к последнему `if`, в нем проверяется, соответствует ли `LowerCase` `да` или `da`. Но в случае отмены `LowerCase` по-прежнему пустая строка, то есть, ни `да`, ни `da`. Поэтому этот блок и выполняется. Вы приведите код в нормальный порядок и тогда понятней станет. Условие, по идее, развилка в логике. У вас отдельно 3 развилки следом друг за другом, развилки есть, а продолжения пути нет)) Рисуйте схему алгоритма сначала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (check == null) {
  ...
} else {
  LowerCase = check.toLowerCase();
  if (LowerCase == 'da' || LowerCase == 'да') {
    alert(`Проверка прошла успешно`);   
  } else {
    ...
  } 
}
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы пожалуйста дать ссылку на этот подход, как вы там его называли? Кажется 'строчные блоки'?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский вряд ли такой подход где-то наглядно описан, это просто **банальная логика** называется)) Если, то ... иначе .... Блок `if + else` покрывает любые возможные случаи. Соответственно, логично все остальное поместить либо в блок if, либо в else. По крайней мере, в вашем простом случае. В сложных же программах надо стремиться к развертыванию простой логической схемы. Нарисуйте древовидную логическую структуру хода программы, функции, где ответвление по условию, а ветки - блоки if (их может быть несколько) и else.

Comment: А как развить эту логику)?
И почему Игорёк удалил все свои и мои комменты? Стыдно стало?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский "Не надо фамильярностей." У меня нет возможности удалять чужие комментарии; я не стыжусь своих комментариев и не удаляю их.

Comment: Ну вы же меня называете на 'ты', то есть вы первыми начали фамильярничать =)

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский Сударь, Вы бредите. Я ни к кому не обращаюсь на "ты" на StackOverflow.

Comment: А нужно ли ставить запятую между if  и else в родительской конструкции else?
Правильно ли оформлять это дело без запятой?

Comment: @ЯнЗамойский Какой еще, черт возьми, "запятой"?